# set a timeout for a $state.go function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, timeout

I'm trying to add a timeout when I call a function on a service. That function runs a process that add tasks to a queue.

Everything's working fine in that process, even the $state.go function, but I'm getting too soon to the view that the routes refers. I can't see the result of the process i'm running because i'm getting to the view before the process start to execute itself.

I was thinking to add a timeout but is not working (or I don't know if I did it wrong)

```
function CreateMigrationCtrl(MigrationService, $state, $timeout) {

...

$timeout($state.go('app.migration'), 3000);
}
```

It's that the right way to use it?

Can I use a timeout to delay the execution of $state.go?

Answer (score 3):

In your code $state.go is invoked immediately and you are passing result to timeout, in other words your code looks like

```
var result = $state.go('app.migration');
$timeout(result, 3000);
```

Instead you have to pass reference to function which should be called after specified amount of time

```
$timeout(function() {
    $state.go('app.migration');
}, 3000);
```

or

```
$timeout($state.go.bind(null, 'app.migration'), 3000);
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian, this was helpful

Answer (score 0):

You should give a `function` to `$timeout`.

```
$timeout(function() {
    $state.go('app.migration');
}, 3000);
```